# Cannot uninstall package on android completely

Tags: android, adb

I am currently developing an android app and have a big problem: I cannot uninstall the development version or install a new version of the app. What I have tried so far:

Rebooting both android and windows device.

`adb uninstall [PACKAGE]`: `Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]`

`adb shell pm list packages -f | grep [PACKAGE]`: Returns nothing

`adb shell pm uninstall --user [USER] [PACKAGE]` with all users from `adb shell pm list users`

`adb install [BUILD/DEBUG VERSION APK]`:

```
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package ***** signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
```

For me this seems like there is some part of the package still left on the device. How can I remove it? What can I do to install my application again. Thanks in advance!

Using a non rooted OnePlus 7 Pro with Android 10 and the latest version of adb on Windows if that matters.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to figure it out what caused this error and/or the inability to install your apk?